# Is sodium hypochlorite 100% concentrate possible?

Tags: boiling-point, melting-point, liquids

Popular bleaching brands like Clorox contain liquid sodium hypochlorite in small concentrations, ranging from 5-12.5% (is this a mass/volume, mass/mass, or volume/volume concentrate?).

Is it possible to achieve a 100% concentrate in liquid form (pure NAClO)? Experimentally, I've found it's boiling point to be around 35°C, but I would assume that its melting point is fairly high in comparison.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hypochlorite) disagrees with your figures.  They give a melting point only for the pentahydrate (18°C, at which point this forms not pure sodium hypochlirite but a solution of one mole sodium hypochlirite to five moles water).  The only reported phase transition for the neat compound is a "boiling point" of 101°C which is actually a decomposition point.

So I would not bet on getting pure liquid sodium hypochlorite, although as mentioned above the pentahydrate can be converted to a fairly concentrated solution.

Comment: So if that (not having anything aside from a pentahydrate to be a 17% concentrate solution max) were to be the case; what would happen if I took a pure tablet of sodium hypochlorite and heated it to  20°C?

Comment: "what would happen if I took a pure tablet of sodium hypochlorite and heated it to 20°C?"  Nothing worth noting.